# How can I have my system ignore touch screen as input, but still give me the x,y coordinate position of the touch?

Tags: touchscreen

I am using a USB touch panel from eGalax (like [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Win10-Compatible-17-Inch-includes-USB-Controller-4-Wire-Resistive-Touch-Screen-Panel-For-photobooth-photo/32809597549.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.22.31ae5dbflpX3n5&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_100031_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_538_537_536,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=fe1c0e75-eea8-42cd-8fc2-bf334446d5f5-3&algo_pvid=fe1c0e75-eea8-42cd-8fc2-bf334446d5f5)). I plan to use it as a position sensor. The x,y coordinate is obtained just fine with the following code:

```
from Xlib import display
data = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data
print data["root_x"], data["root_y"]
```

However, every time the touchscreen input is received it also affects the computer, just like I am using a mouse. Obviously, this is what the device is supposed to do by default ^ ^. But is it possible to make my computer ignore the touch input and read only the x,y coordinate of the touch panel?

Answer (score 1):

I've found an alternative solution. I read the touchscreen output with Arduino with [this library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_TouchScreen). Then the reading is sent back the computer via serial port in real-time. The library can also detect whether the panel is touched or not, which is very helpful.